# Remote Host Terminated The Handshake , SSL peer shut down incorrectly with Intellij Editor 2020.3

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, intellij-idea

Refer the attached screenshot - Its like building a Gradle (6.4.1 and Java-11) based spring boot application in Intellij Editor 2020.3 and MacOS(11.4 BigSur). Also used the latest version of IntelliJ, Referred various other post but not found any working solution.

Remote Host Terminated The Handshake, SSL peer shut down incorrectly [image]

Comment: Provide full textual output from Build tool window and idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) file after reproducing.

Comment: Does command line Gradle build work?

Comment: Command line did not help !

Comment: @Andrey I found similar problem in datagrip as well,Failed to download,Remote host terminated the handshake, and followed the following and then it worked : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010798199-DataGrip-upgraded-to-2021-1-2-error-occurs-when-connecting-to-database-SSLHandshakeException-